# Trying to access array offset on value of type null using Laravel and jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

please don't tag this as duplicate because all of the answer here doesn't applicable to my issues.

Let me show you the error I am having

[image]

I am using a jquery to petch the value of "province_id" base from the value of the "region". what I am notice is if the record has already a value, there's no error but if null what it should do is to Petch the value of "region" which is not null it has default value.

for the edit in my controller

```
    public function edit($id, Profile $model)
{
    $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    $profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);

    // Turn this array into a Collection
    $profileSourceIncome = collect(explode(',', $profile->source_income));

    $province_id = Province::where('province_id', $profile->province_id)->first();
    $city_id = City::where('city_id', $profile->city_id)->first();
    $code = Barangay::where('code', $profile->barangay_id)->first();

    return view('dashboard.profile.edit', compact('model','profile'))   
        ->with('province_id', $province_id)
        ->with('city_id', $city_id)
        ->with('code', $code)
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('profileSourceIncome', $profileSourceIncome);
}
```

form.blade

```
<div class="form-group {{$errors->has('region_id')}}">
    <label>Region:</label>
    {{app('form')->select('region_id', $regions, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'region_id'])}}
    {{$errors->first('region_id')}}
</div>

<div class="form-group {{$errors->has('province_id')}}">
    <label>Province: </label>
    {{app('form')->select('province_id', [], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'province_id'])}}
    {{$errors->first('province_id')}}
</div>


@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var address = {
                province: '{{$province_id['province_id']}}',
                city: '{{$city_id['city_id']}}',
                barangay: '{{$code['code']}}',
            };

            $('#region_id').on('change', function () {
                $.getJSON('{{config('address.prefix')}}/provinces/' + this.value, function (data) {
                    var options = '';
                    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                        var selected = '';
                        if (data.province_id == address.province) {
                            selected = ' selected ';
                        }
                        options += '<option value="' + data.province_id + '"' + selected + '>' + data.name + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#province_id').html(options);
                    $('#province_id').change();
                });
            });

            $('#province_id').on('change', function () {
                $.getJSON('{{config('address.prefix')}}/cities/' + this.value, function (data) {
                    var options = '';
                    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                        var selected = '';
                        if (data.city_id == address.city) {
                            selected = ' selected ';
                        }
                        options += '<option value="' + data.city_id + '"' + selected + '>' + data.name + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#city_id').html(options);
                    $('#city_id').change();
                });
            });

            $('#city_id').on('change', function () {
                $.getJSON('{{config('address.prefix')}}/barangays/' + this.value, function (data) {
                    var options = '';
                    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                        var selected = '';
                        if (data.code == address.barangay) {
                            selected = ' selected ';
                        }
                        options += '<option value="' + data.code + '"' + selected + '>' + data.name + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#barangay_id').html(options);
                    $('#barangay_id').change();
                });
            });
            $('#region_id').change();
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: in your view file,  instead of ``$province_id['province_id']`` it should be ``$province_id`` and also for other values too.

Comment: Sidenote, do not do `::all()->where()->first()`; this is loading every record in your database into memory, then `array_searching` it and returning the first one that matches... This is (well, _can be_) incredibly inefficient. Just do `::where()->first();`

Comment: Next, if you're conditionally defining `$province_id = '';`, how would you expect `$province_id['province_id']` to work? `''['province_id']` is not valid PHP... You should handle the `else` part of `if ($profile->region_id!=null) {` better, or check what `$province_id` is before trying to use it... `$province_id ? $province_id->province_id : ''` for example.

Comment: Or, if you're only every going to access `['province_id']`, don't bother querying... Just do `$province_id = $profile->province_id`, and access as `{{ $province_id }}`... Your code has **a lot** of holes in it...

Comment: I just update my controller. I am still having same error if the value of the record is null. but it is still working if the record has a value